# Label height in Cell won't change height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, label

I have a cell with a few labels init. One of the label is for a question. My app has different questions with different lengths. So I need my label to have a dynamical height. I want to achieve this with auto layout. When I run my app with my current auto layout it doesn't change the height (See pictures) . I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have changed the number of lines of the label to 0 and I have added:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

to my viewDidLoad(), but it won't change the height of my label. The weird thing is that it will change the height when the view is changing to an other view. See thing Youtube link to see what I am talking about: [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARAjlOEHc_0&feature=youtu.be). Change the speed of the video to the slowest to see the best results. It's happening around 0:04 seconds into the video.

Constraints:
[image: Auto layout]

[image: AutoLayout]

Label on device:

[image: Label on device]

Autor label Constraints:

[image: Autor label]

Bannerview Constraints:

[image: Banner view contraints]

Comment: did you try to add only a label and debug which view is breaking resizing?

Comment: Yes I have! When I delete every label except for the one with the question it still won't change the height of the label till the view change.

Comment: Are you expecting the change in label at the runtime?

Comment: Set your labels `numberOfLines = 0` and don't use any static height constraints. Set tableView's dynamic rowHeight ->  `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // whatever you want` `tableView.rowHeight = UTableView.automaticDimension`.

Comment: The question needs first to load from the Firebase database. I have done this in my tableviewCell Viewcontroller. When the questions is loaded the label needs to display this question. This seems to work fine, because the questions will be displayed in the label. But I want to have as soon as the questions loads from the Firebase database that the label will change its height dynamically. I am not really familiar with tableview cells, but has it maybe something to do with the loading of the question in the tableviewCell Viewcontroller?

Comment: When data loading is complete you can do `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: I think your other components compressing your question label. Use vertical stackView in your cell. Don't use any static height constraints. And use techniques mentioned in my previous comments.

Comment: Adding `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` seems to do the trick. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the `tableViewCell` take the `height` according to the `label's` `text` i.e. ***Loading...***

Once you get `Questions` response from the `Firebase`, to reflect the changes in the `tableViewCell's` `content` and its `height`, you need to reload the whole `tableView`, i.e.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Call the above code once you receive the *API response* and after updating the `dataSource` that you're using for the `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

add all constraint with respect to superview of that resizing label. 
also use

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. It still won't change the height of the label till the view will change!

Comment: it'll definetily work use tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100(or whatever constant)

Comment: have  you added  all constraint with respect to content view of that particular label?

Comment: Yes i have added all constraints with respect to the content view of the label.

Comment: add this too
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping